# Converting Varchar Date into timestamp in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a date field as varchar type and need to convert it into Timestamp as i need to apply datediff function over it. Below is the varchar date format i have

**20210201053414**

This is 1st of Feb 2021 05:34:14 AM

I tried
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('20210201053414','yyyyMMddHHmmss')

but it says

Can't parse '20210201053414' as timestamp with format 'yyyyMMddHHmmss'

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('20210201053414','YYYYMMDDHH24MISS');
```

The issue is about MM - it should be MI. Please check the Format Specifiers:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/date-time-input-output.html#about-the-format-specifiers-in-this-section